# Google console showing 0 device compatibility

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

While publishing my android application on google play, it is showing 0 device compatible. Can anyone help me out why is that so?
But while using on many other devices it is working

Piece of manifest is as shown below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.setParameters"/>
```

And in gradle

```
    android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked many other links and have changed configuration for camera, which was camera2 and now it is camera. I am dont know where is what going wrong and I am publishing app for the first time on google play.

Comment: I think you are making anything else wrong there is nothing wrong in both f your provided sample

Comment: hmm let me remove all uses-features and try... let me see what happens... does that shows any device compatible... if yes then some problems in features I guess... else somewhere else

Comment: Do you have supports-screens or compatible-screens in your manifest?  I think one or the other is required.  See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html).

Comment: I have not added any of them... Well let me try even that

Comment: do you genrate signAPK? for play store upload?

Comment: Ofcourse signed apk and release build

Comment: I have removed all features and now it was showing 7067 devices supported

Comment: I have also added support screen as mentioned by @qbix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MAPS_RECEIVE` permissions do not have the same package names --

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.stylabs.styfi.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

vs

```
<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

For recent versions of google maps, I believe it safe to just remove those as they are no longer required, but if you keep them, the package names should match.

Per comment below, your GCM permissions also look wrong because they don't match either of the `MAPS_RECEIVE` package names.  They do match each other, so might not be cauing filtering out of devices in the store, but will prevent GCM from working properly, so those packages should be updated with your package name, too.

Comment: i think GCM have also this mistck

Comment: @VishalPatel  You are right, the GCM permissions match each other, but do not match either of the MAPS_RECEIVE permissions.

Comment: I actually forgot to change that while putting that question over here... sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

If you list a `<uses-feature>` string that doesn't actually exist, then you'll match no devices.  To the best of my knowledge, there's no such feature as

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.setParameters"/>
```

Remove that, or at least set `android:required="false"` for it.